# Adding Animation Class Affects Other Classes

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm writing a function that replaces the mouse pointer when idle. Currently the mouse is green when in the browser window and turns red and pulses when the mouse is moved outside of the window.I added the *.pulse* class as a webkit animation to my *.circle* class.  My problem is that the inner "idle" circle will not remain the same size; instead it moves with the animation. How do I keep the inner circle a fixed size? Thank you.

**NOTES:**

- *.pulse* is the webkit animation
- *.circle* is the inner circle
- *goActive*
  is the "user-active" function, *goInactive* is the "user-idle" function.
  In these two functions I added/ removed the *.pulse* class to
  add/remove the animation.

If there's a more sophisticated way to do this, please let me know. I'm very new.

```js
 var TimeoutID;

 function inputdetect() {
  // attaches event handler to specified event
  // takes event as string, function to run, and optional boolean
  // to indicate when the event propogates
  // these are false, so events "bubble up"
  this.addEventListener("mousemove",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("mousedown",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("mousewheel",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("keypress",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("touchmove",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("DOMmousescroll",resetTimer,false);
  this.addEventListener("MSpointermove",resetTimer,false);

  startTimer();
 }

 inputdetect();

 function startTimer() {
  //waits two seconds before calling inactive
  TimeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive,2000); // does it need to take the window variable??

 }

 function resetTimer(e) {
  window.clearTimeout(TimeoutID);
  goActive();

 }

 function goActive() {

  //what happens when the UI is not idle

  $('p').text("The UI is not idle.");
  $('.cursory').css("background-color","green");
  $('.cursory').removeClass("pulse");
  startTimer();
 }

 function goInactive() {
  
  $('p').text("The UI is idle.");
  // REPLACING CURSOR WHEN UI IS IDLE
  //this part won't work
  $('.cursory').css("background-color","red");
  $('.cursory').addClass("pulse");
  

 }

// THIS changes the pointer to a css element
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.cursory').css({
   left: e.pageX,
   top: e.pageY
   });
  });
 
});
```

```css
 html {
   cursor: none;
   
 }
 .cursory {

   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
     padding: 5px;
     
   background-color: green;
   background-clip: content-box;

   position: fixed;
   
 }

 .pulse {

  border: 3px solid blue;
  -webkit-border-radius:30px;
  height:18px;
  width:18px;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  z-index:-1;
      left:-7px;
     top:-7px;
     -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
     opacity: 0.0

 }

 @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "cursory"></div>
<!--this is where the HTML will go*/-->
<p>hello</p>
```

**TL;DR:**

I suspect I've overwritten the border conditions for the inner circle when I add the webkit one. How can I ensure the circles maintain independence from each other but are still triggered by the same event?

Comment: Could you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: learned something new today! (hopefully I also learn to fix this)

Comment: You want the red circle to be the same size as the green circle? Change the width & height in .pulse to be the same as in .cursory. I'd then us box-shadow for the animating border.

Comment: so something like     @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: box-shadow:0px; opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: box-shadow:18px; opacity: 0.0;}